# Update Entity Not Being Tracked By Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am building an API with .NET Core 2.0 and Entity Framework Core.

I have a database of users. When the login URI is called, I find the user in the database like so:

```
User user = _usersRepository.GetUserByEmail(model.Email);
```

I then create a token (Guid) that is stored in a dictionary alongside the user object that I just fetched. The token is returned to the consumer and is then required for authorization.

For controller actions that require authorization, a custom attribute fetches the current user object from the dictionary (using their token) and passes it to the controller using HttpContext.Items.

*I now have the currently logged in User object inside the controller.*

Inside the controller, I would like to alter a property of this user object and then update the database entry for that user.

This is what I would like to be able to do (simplified):

```
User authenticatedUser = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("authenticatedUser" ...)
authenticatedUser.Username = "John Doe";  
_usersRepository.SaveChanges();
```

The following works, but introduces an extra database query, which seems pointless and inefficient seeing as I have the user object right there as `authenticatedUser`:

```
User authenticatedUser = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("authenticatedUser" ...)   
User user = _usersRepository.GetUserById(authenticatedUser.Id);  
user.Username = "John Doe";  
_usersRepository.SaveChanges();
```

**How can I save the changes made to `authenticatedUser` without having to fetch from my database again?**

Comment: I believe if you use `Attach`, you will be able to perform `SaveChanges` without every calling the `GetUserById`

Comment: I have seen `Attach` before but i'm not familiar with how I would use it in this instance. I will do some Googling but any more advice would be appreicated. Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `Attach`

```
User authenticatedUser = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("authenticatedUser" ...)   
if(authenticatedUser != null)
{
    _usersRepository.Attach(authenticatedUser);  
    authenticatedUser.Username = "John Doe";  
    _usersRepository.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response. I've been stressing over this all day and it was so simple! :)

Comment: glad it helped :)